# How to Listen to KeyCode Event if the Application is not Visible?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, keypress

I created an application that runs in the background using Visual Basic 2010.

The code is:

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub
```

My question is on how to listen to KeyPress event like a combination of Ctrl+Alt+J and when this keys are pressed, the form will popup again.

I know there's a Form1_KeyPress event but that will trigger only if the form has focus.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a keyboard hook as described in here: [How to set a hook in Visual Basic .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319524).